# How to Import .ibw files in Mathematica

Tags: import

Can anyone tell me how to import .ibw (igor binary wave) into *Mathematica*?

Comment: Do you have any links to discriptions of this format?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries. It is a proprietary format used by IGOR Pro app. Here is a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IGOR_Pro)

Comment: A possibility would be to use R through RLink. There is a package to read *.ibw files into R ([IgorR](https://github.com/jefferis/IgorR)) that you may be able to use through RLink. The file format specification is available in WaveMetrics Technical Note 003 ([link a zip file on their FTP site with C code as well](ftp://ftp.wavemetrics.net/IgorPro/Technical_Notes/TN003.zip)) but the format is complicated enough that I wouldn't want to re-implement an import routine.

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot :o). Now I can import ibw in Mathematica.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. To benefit the community, would you post an answer to your own question detailing the steps to take, so other people will be able to find this if they have your same problem? Answering your own questions is encouraged on stackexchange!

Comment: I tried to run REvaluate["install.packages('IgorR')"] but REvaluate["read.ibw(...)"] returns Error: could not find function. I'm on Windows...

Comment: Looks like I needed require(IgorR). Now I get: general error in function RLink`Private`withRTemporaryVariables.

Comment: See also: https://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/3131/ (Mathematica package from 1995 for reading Igor Pro files)

See also:  (via Python External Evaluation system) https://github.com/MiLL4U/ibwpy